# Bit sequence from USB HID Joystick

Tags: arduino, usb

I wanted to connect a USB HID Controller to an Arduino and use it to control a Remote Controlled car.

But I'm unable to find what bit sequence is sent when a button is pressed on the joystick. I would like to find what that sequence is.

I'm running a dual-boot system with both Linux and Windows, so software that works on either one is fine.

Comment: You're running dual-boot Linux/Windows on Arduino?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I'm unable to find what bit sequence is sent when a button is pressed on the joystick. I would like to find what that sequence is.

There isn't one.

USB devices operate on a polling basis. They do not communicate over the bus outside of a transaction from the host. Getting to the point of communicating with the device takes a significant amount of work to enumerate the device and configure it with an address.

Even once that's all done, there isn't a specific message used when a button is pressed. The status report response from the device will have a field which includes a bitmap representing the buttons on the mouse -- one of the bits in that field will be set when the button is being held down, and clear when it is not.

Since the Arduino lacks a USB host peripheral, and runs at a relatively low speed (8-16 MHz) compared to USB line rate (1.5 or 12 Mbit/sec), it will be excruciatingly difficult, if not impossible, to implement a USB host on an Arduino device. Use an accessory which implements a USB host for you, like the USB Host Shield, or use a different microcontroller which supports USB host operation.

Answer (score 2):

USB really isn't that easy, but luckily somebody has already written a library and example code, [you can find it here](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/tree/master/examples/HID/USBHIDJoystick). Also code that works on Linux or Windows would be irrelevant to Arduino.

The above example uses the [USB Host shield](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-usb-host-shield). You need to have an Arduino that supports USB Host mode, not just USB Device mode. Usually these Arduino's have USB-A ports or USB OTG ports.

By the way, if you have specific Arduino questions, there is an [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) that is better equipped to handle these types of questions.

Comment: Actually I wanted to check out what data was sent via the USB when I press a button. By Linux or Windows I meant codes or apps I can use to find that out. You may call it curiosity

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka something like a [USB sniffer](https://freeusbanalyzer.com/)/analyzer is what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, what you want is the ***usbhid-dump*** package for linux. This will print out in real time the hid descriptor for your usb hid joystick.